# Parallax code working on JSFiddle but not on my website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, parallax

so I'm redesigning my website (long overdue), and I'm attempting to get paralax working.  The concept seems simple enough, right?

I got a working project on JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3Vznc/)

That is EXACTLY the result I want.  However, if you go to the page [here](http://www.lampitosgames.com/new) on my website, the background  is very jerky and it does not look remotely natural.  I cannot figure out why.  The code on my site is the exact same.  Here is the basic version

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(window).scroll(function() {
var pos = $(window).scrollTop();
var element = $("#paralaxImageWrapper");
var top = element.offset().top;
var height = element.height();
// Check if totally above or totally below viewport
if (top + height > pos || top < pos + windowHeight) {
    $("#paralaxImageWrapper").css('-webkit-transform',"translate(0px, " + $(window).scrollTop()/1.5 + "px)");
    $("#paralaxImageWrapper").css('-moz-transform',"translate(0px, " + $(window).scrollTop()/1.5 + "px)");
    $("#paralaxImageWrapper").css('-ms-transform',"translate(0px, " + $(window).scrollTop()/1.5 + "px)");
}
});
});
```

Help as to what exactly is going on (does jsfiddle have something I don't?) is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Both versions work the same for me on Chrome (Mac).

Comment: This is wrong, change `<img class="headerLogoImage" src="images\header\logo.png"/>` to `<img class="headerLogoImage" src="images/header/logo.png"/>`. Aswell `<img class="paralaxImage" src="images\paralaxHighlightsScroller\backgrounds\guitar.jpg"\>` to `<img class="paralaxImage" src="images/paralaxHighlightsScroller/backgrounds/guitar.jpg" \>` and you dont seem to have a starting & ending `<html>` tags. Fix it and we can get a better overview at your page compared to the Fiddle.

Comment: huh, I guess we're looking for browser issues then.  I'm using Torch (supposedly a chrome mod).  Looks like the issue is on Torch and IE, then.  Firefox and Chrome work.  And I'm not sure about safari.

Comment: @urbz fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

JSFiddle is using jQuery version 1.10.1 while your site is using jQuery 1.9.1.  Try using http://jquerylatest.com/ and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: thanks for noticing that!  But it unfortunately fixed none of my issues.